# carousel not working with ui-bootstrap and meanjs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, meanjs

I am currently using meanjs as the framework to work on a project. I am stuck with carousel not being able to work. Basically, I kept it simple by removing the addSlide() as I only intend to display the slides. But it is not even working and console is throwing out an error which I do not understand. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
angular.module('core').controller('CarouselController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.interval = 3000;
        $scope.slides = [
        {image: 'http://placekitten.com/200/200',text: 'Kitten.'},
        {image: 'http://placekitten.com/225/200',text: 'Kitty!'},
        {image: 'http://placekitten.com/250/200',text: 'Cat.'},
        {image: 'http://placekitten.com/275/200',text: 'Feline!'}
        ];
    }
])
.directive('disableAnimation', function($animate){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $attrs.$observe('disableAnimation', function(value){
                $animate.enabled(!value, $element);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="CarouselController">
        <div style="height:305px">
            <carousel interval="interval" disable-animation="true">
                <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4> Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                        <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
                    </div>
                </slide>
            </carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Error description on console:

> ```
> TypeError: undefined is not a function
> at link (../lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:684:20)
> at ../lib/angular/angular.js:7113:44
> at nodeLinkFn (../lib/angular/angular.js:6711:13)
> at delayedNodeLinkFn (../lib/angular/angular.js:6933:11)
> at compositeLinkFn (../lib/angular/angular.js:6105:13)
> at publicLinkFn (../lib/angular/angular.js:6001:30)
> at boundTranscludeFn (../lib/angular/angular.js:6125:21)
> at controllersBoundTransclude (../lib/angular/angular.js:6732:18)
> at ngRepeatAction (../lib/angular/angular.js:20625:15)
> at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (../lib/angular/angular.js:12409:13) <div
> ng-class="{
> 'active': leaving || (active &amp;&amp; !entering),
> 'prev': (next || active) &amp;&amp; direction=='prev',
> 'next': (next || active) &amp;&amp; direction=='next',
> 'right': direction=='prev',
> 'left': direction=='next'   }" class="item text-center ng-isolate-scope" ng-transclude="" ng-repeat="slide in slides"
> active="slide.active"> angular.js:10071 Resource interpreted as Image
> but transferred with MIME type text/plain:
> "http://placekitten.com/200/200".
> ```

Comment: https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/524 might be helpful to you